# Creating dropdown fields within a table

Tags: redcap

I am trying to create a table that will have a scenario on the first column, then in three additional columns next to it I want to have dropdowns with their choices. I know if I do a field embed that would work but there are around 60 different scenarios. That would mean having to create 180 different dropdown menu fields to then embed into the table. Is there any way to prevent having to make that many.

I initially made one dropdown field thinking I would be able to just embed that one in all of the scenario choices since they all have the same choice options. However, when I went to the survey to test it, it created an error ( ERROR: The field "prob" has already been embedded on this page. Fields cannot be embedded more than once.) and stated I am only able to embed a field once.

Comment: show the code you tried

Comment: Also you mention an error, please post it.  These suggestings are requirements for questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion doesn't get you away from making all the fields, but instead simplifies making all the fields.
You could make your first scenario, export your data dictionary and then use Excel to copy prob_1 into prob_2, prob_3... Last import the modified data dictionary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).